# Sass commands aren't working, but it's installed?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, styles, sass

When I try to use sass commands in my "styles.css" file, they don't work. Example:

`$navbarBackgroundHighLight: white;`

rails version: Rails 4.1.0,
bootstrap version: 3.1.1.1,
sass version: Sass 3.3.7 (Maptastic Maple).

I've tried everything. Any help is greatly appreciated!

When I try to add .scss to the end of "styles.css" I get:

Sass::SyntaxError in Pages#home
Showing C:/WINDOWS/code/code/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #6 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive.
Load paths:
  C:/WINDOWS/code/code/app/assets/images
  C:/WINDOWS/code/code/app/assets/javascripts
  C:/WINDOWS/code/code/app/assets/stylesheets
  C:/WINDOWS/code/code/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/WINDOWS/code/code/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-2.2.2/lib/assets/javascripts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1/vendor/assets/fonts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.0/vendor/assets/javascripts
  C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bootstrap-sass-3.1.1.1/vendor/assets/stylesheets
  (in C:/WINDOWS/code/code/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:37)
Extracted source (around line #6):
3
4
5
6
7
8
9

```
<head>
    <title>CODE</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Rails.root: C:/WINDOWS/code/code

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:37
app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:6:in `_app_views_layouts_application_html_erb___669748780_8349660'

Comment: Why did you delete previous same question? Now it looks like spam, and could be flagged.

Comment: Please show the full error and the part of your css/sass file which the error affects.  From this there's nothing we can do to help you.

Answer (score 0):

The file should be called `styles.css.scss` for it to work properly

Comment: Right. `style.css` is not run through the (SASS) preprocessor since it's lacking the proper extension. Preprocessors are run from right to left according to the file's extension(s) and they are chainable - if you had a file `style.css.scss.erb` it would first be run through ERB, then through SASS.

Comment: Hard to say what could cause this problem without digging into the code.

"Line #6" means that there is something wrong with your stylesheets but you probably already knew that. `File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-responsive` could be a hint - you probably have something like `/*= require bootstrap-responsive */` in your `application.css` but are you sure that this file actually exists somewhere in your load path (`app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css` or `vendor/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap-responsive.css`)?

Comment: When I make a "bootstrap-responsive.css" file it disables the "styles.css" code. When I remove `@import bootstrap-responsive` from "styles.css" all together, then it lets me add .scss to the end of "styles.css" without an error. However the problem still remains, sass commands don't work. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Changing from **css** to **sass** you may have to reorganize the file (for sass syntax). Here's what I have in the top of my `application.css.scss`:

```
/*
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */

@import "bootstrap";
@import "bootstrap/responsive";
```

You also have to check if you have the bootstrap gem declared correctly in you Gemfile:

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

Hope this helps.